# Unable to connect to the internet after upgrading to Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: networking, 22.04, dns, do-release-upgrade, virtualbox-networking

I just upgraded my ubuntu version twice till I got to the version 22.04. I needed to do so because I need to install a package that it depends on a package whose version is only available at Ubuntu 22.04. The thing is that I am unable to connect to the internet so that I can download the package - and also work. I will leave here some outputs of commands I've tried already for the last two days. I've been through lots of questions on the forum, but none of them was able to do the trick.
Due to that, I decided to post my own question then.
Thanks in advance!

```
systemctl list-unit-files | grep -i network
```

Gives the output:

```
    networkd-dispatcher.service                    masked          enabled
    NetworkManager-dispatcher.service              enabled         enabled
    NetworkManager-wait-online.service             enabled         enabled
    NetworkManager.service                         enabled         enabled
    systemd-network-generator.service              disabled        enabled
    systemd-networkd-wait-online.service           disabled        disabled
    systemd-networkd.service                       disabled        enabled
    systemd-networkd.socket                        disabled        enabled
    network-online.target                          static          -
    network-pre.target                             static          -
    network.target                                 static          -
```

`systemctl restart networking`

Gives:
`Failed to restart networking.service: Unit networking.service not found.`

`ping 192.168.178.1 -c 3`
Gives:
`ping: connect: Network is unreachable`

`sudo service network-manager restart`  Gives: `Failed to restart network-manager.service: Unit network-manager.service not found.`

This is my resolv.conf:
[resolv.conf file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RSO9Y.png)

I thought it was a firewall issue as I've seen in some questions out there:
But  `sudo ufw enable` or any related `ufw` command gives:
`sudo: ufw: command not found`

Then, the command `sudo apt-get update` at some point gives:
`Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'`

And I believe it's obvious since I don't have internet connection, so I can't fetch any data to upload or install any packages.

Also, the two icons related to internet connection at the right up corner display the following:
[Network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7cB6e.png)
[Wifi connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CvZq5.png)

To finish, I believe it's important to note that I'm running Ubuntu on VMBox

`lsb_release -a` gives:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy
```

Comment: Since it is a VM, you may find it simpler to fresh install ubuntu 22.04

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi, do you mean by deleting my current iso and downloading ubuntu 22.04 in the VM?

Comment: Yes. Download the ISO of Ubuntu 22.04 (or Xubuntu 22.04, since it is lightweight, and you are running it in VM), and install it in Virtualbox